# Updating feature geometry from attribute fields in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, geometry, update, xy

I know how to get the geometry (x,y) into Attribute fields with the Calculator, but I can't figure out how to update the geometry from values contained in attributes.

I am trying `Field Calculator > Update existing field > <geometry>`, but I can't find how to assign my `"x"` and `"y"` fields to the actual feature geometry.

I don't want to manually drag each point with the vertex editor, or type in each coordinate. I have to update many points.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assuming you have chosen `<geometry>` field in the `Update existing field` drop down list, the expression you need would be:

```
geom_from_wkt('POINT('||"x"||' '||"y"||')')
```

Comment: Awesome - I would never have figured out the || by myself... Thank you for the quick response.

Comment: Great! Thanks @Benoit_W :) You would have found out that sooner or later.

Comment: The syntax is actually quite misleading. Here is the correct one with example coordinates:

`geom_from_wkt('POINT('||'31.797788'||' '||'30.729471'||')')`

Notice the single quotes. Using double quotes in QGIS 2/3 will cause an error as it mistakens the x and y values as field names.

Comment: @15Step This syntax is reading values from "x" and "y" fields, such field names were set by OP.

Comment: I misunderstood the question, sorry about that! I think the comment could still be useful for updating numerical coordinates in the <geometry> field.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use the [`make_point()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#make-point) function together with updated fields `"x"` and `"y"`.

***before change :***
[image: case1_before]

***window :***
[image: window]

***after change :***
[image: case1_after]

Answer (score 1):

I modified this a bit to move a selection of points into a spread out line along a vertical axis.

```
geom_from_wkt('POINT('||$x||' '||((@row_number*100)+$y)||')')
```

The 100 can be changed to whatever is appropriate for your area and scale.  I imagine that this could be further modified to create a grid, but I didn't have time to try.