# Method to convert all 'overlapping' points to exact same geometry in QGIS 3.4

Tags: qgis, point, geometry, qgis-3

I have a point vector layer with approximately 2.5 million points, many of which share the same or a very similar geometry (within 1 m of each other).

I would like to know if I can bulk amend the geometry of these points so they are exactly the same if they are within that 1 meter threshold in the X-Y plane?

The majority of 'overlapping' points do share the exact same geometry so ideally I would want to amend those points that fall outside the majority to have the same geometry.

I am familiar with PyQGIS but not confident in it's use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tool "Snap geometries" in the processing toolbox can help you.

Give two times your layer (input and reference layer), set the tolerance to 1 meter and select the best snapping behavior for your case (i.e. align nodes, don't add new).

Comment: thanks, unfortunately I receive a crash report whenever I run this which seems to be because of the size of my data set which I will have to raise.

Comment: Monitor your system while running it, if it runs out of RAM it should be visible.

Comment: Thanks @bugmenot123, it would appear that RAM is the issue. I will have to segment my data set

Answer (score 0):

this might be of help - try using the calculator and referencing the  field and updating the X & Y to specific locations

geom_from_wkt('POINT('||'31.797788'||' '||'30.729471'||')')

further info at -

[QGIS update feature geometry from attribute fields](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/285634/qgis-update-feature-geometry-from-attribute-fields)